# creating local account from csv but how to omit already created accounts?

Tags: powershell, user-accounts

I need to tweak this script to Create a batch of local users from a CSV but skipping an already made account. I can create just fine but how to I omit the local accounts that already exist

```
$computer = $Env:ComputerName
$text = "C:\accounts.csv"
$user = import-csv -path $text
   foreach($strUser) in $user)
{
 $user = $struser.user
 $password = $struser.password
 $description =  $struser.description
 $group = $struser.group
 Clear-Host
 $ObjOU = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"
 $objUser = $objOU.Create("User", $user)
 $objUser.setpassword($password)
 $objUser.put("description",$description)
 $objUser.SetInfo()
 $objGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$group"
 $objGroup.add("WinNT://$computer/$user")
 $objGroup.SetInfo()
}
```

Comment: It failed due to You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\AltirisScript0B427C10272370E8748.ps1:12 char:12
+ If($user - <<<< notin ($ObjOU.Children|Where{$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}
))
+ CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Comment: What expression would I use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#setting Variables 
$computer = $Env:ComputerName
$text = "C:\ProgramData\Bridge Operators.csv"
$user = import-csv -path $text
foreach($strUser in $user)
{
 $user = $struser.user
 $password = $struser.password
 $description =  $struser.description
 $group = $struser.group
 Clear-Host  
##First check if user exists
$objComputer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer,computer"
$colUsers = ($objComputer.psbase.children | Where-Object {$_.psBase.schemaClassName -eq "User"} | Select-Object -expand Name)
$userFound = $colUsers -contains $user
if (! $userFound) {
  write-host "The $user account did not exist."
  write-host "Creating $user"
 $ObjOU = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"
 $objUser = $objOU.Create("User", $user)
 $objUser.setpassword($password)
 $objUser.put("description",$description)
 $objUser.SetInfo()
 $objGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$group"
 $objGroup.add("WinNT://$computer/$user")
 $objGroup.SetInfo()
}
else {
  write-host "$user account exists."
  write-host "skipping"
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the local user accounts from info that you are already pulling. Then just filter against that before creating a user.

```
$computer = $Env:ComputerName
$text = "C:\accounts.csv"
$user = import-csv -path $text
$ObjOU = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"
   foreach($strUser in $user)
{
 $user = $struser.user
 $password = $struser.password
 $description =  $struser.description
 $group = $struser.group
 Clear-Host
 If($user -notin ($ObjOU.Children|Where{$_.SchemaClassName -eq  'user'}).Name){
    $objUser = $objOU.Create("User", $user)
    $objUser.setpassword($password)
    $objUser.put("description",$description)
    $objUser.SetInfo()
 }
 $objGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$group"
 $objGroup.add("WinNT://$computer/$user")
 $objGroup.SetInfo()
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help - -So it doesn't like the IF statement and will not create the accounts.  It want's a value expression on the right had side of the '-' operator. 11 char 12.

Comment: FIXED! It now creates the account if not found and skips any account already created.